# Python: list.remove() behave wiredly

Tags: python

```
def get_variables(cells):
    domains = [1,2,3,4]
    variables = {}
    for cell in cells:
        if(cell == "C11"):
            variables[cell] = [1]
        elif(cell == "C22"):
            variables[cell] = [2]
        elif(cell == "C33"):
            variables[cell] = [3]
        elif(cell == "C44"):
            variables[cell] = [4]
        else:
            variables[cell] = domains

cells = ['C'+x+y for x in "1234" for y in "1234"]
variables = get_variables(cells)
csp = CSP(variables, constraints, assigned)
pprint(csp.variables)
csp.variables["C12"].remove(1)
print(csp.variables["C13"])
```

```
output: 
{'C11': [1],
 'C12': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C13': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C14': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C21': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C22': [2],
 'C23': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C24': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C31': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C32': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C33': [3],
 'C34': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C41': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C42': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C43': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C44': [4]}
[2, 3, 4]
```

It is supposed to remove 1 from "C12", instead it did it to "C13". Why is that? I guess something related to memory location? This really drives me crazy. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: you have defined C12 and C13 as the same list.

Comment: is there a way to only remove 1 from C12?

Comment: please edit the question mentioning the csp.variables fully and how it looks like

Comment: `get_variables` doesn't return anything. This code is not even close to a [MCVE], because it can't *possibly* produce the behavior you claim to see. Post something that actually reproduces the problem in isolation, don't make us guess at all the code you omitted that is necessary for the problem to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that "C12" and "C13" don't contain different lists, but the same one.  Meaning that no matter how you modify either one, the other will be affected in the same way.

To see this clearly, print `csp.variables` at the end instead of just "CSP12".

The mistake is this line:

```
variables[cell] = domains
```

Because every `variable[cell]` is given the same list. Which is a [mutable type](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRxrvqmJX3AhXnyYUKHWCaCxkQFnoECD8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8056130%2Fimmutable-vs-mutable-types&usg=AOvVaw1ie8dPv97vdTzMkgwz02Et). So when it is modified, it will be modified in place.

To fix this you could give the cells copies or slices, which are different objects:

```
variables[cell] = domains.copy()
```

or

```
variables[cell] = domains[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
desired_key = 'C12'
for key in csp.keys():
  if key == desired_key:
    del csp[key][0]


print(csp)
``
```